# How to solve unwanted Angular Routing behavior?

Tags: angular, angular-router

The Angular docs provide clear instructions on how to add routing to their apps. I'm getting weird behavior in implementing what should be a page redirect. I've updated NPM, created multiple test servers, and still, when I type in the new page in the URL I get interesting behavior. Sometimes it just stays on app.component and nothing visually happens at all.

**Behavior**

[image]

[image]

**And the Code**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've used Ionic/Angular for more than a year and have never had issues with Routing. The Rofl component is being accepted by the router, but the HTML of that component is just a `<p>` tag. When I run "ctrl + f" on the "app.component.html" there is no *rofl* search term anywhere. Why are "app" and "rofl" components being combined in the view?

Comment: Where is your `<router-outlet>`? I'd guess that it is located within the AppComponent below the default page.

Comment: It's there: https://hastebin.com/uquyusajac.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routed content is displayed in place of a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag.

As you created your project (`ng new myProject`) and chose to add the routing feature by selecting the prompt option, a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` has been added at the end of your *AppComponent* template.

So by routing to '/rofl', it displays the base content of your application (the AppCompnent) followed by the content of the routed component (RoflComponent).

Comment: Yes, and for anyone reading this who wants a pure page relocation, make sure to make ` <router-outlet></router-outlet> `  the only thing in your app.component.html. This works!